# Connect Windows Phone 8 Application to database using WCF

Tags: c#

I'm trying to connect my windows phone application to external database on SQL Server using WCF ,but there is an exception appears to me 
"An exception of type "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException" occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"

Any help please ???

Comment: Post your code please?

Comment: please explain more, with the code.

Comment: I added a service reference and create a client object of it to call all functions

Comment: InventoryServiceClient service = new InventoryServiceClient();
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int productID = Int32.Parse(txtProductID.Text);
            service.GetProductCompleted += service_GetProductCompleted;
        }
the exception showed in that line  InventoryServiceClient service = new InventoryServiceClient();